# prevent DESCryptoServiceProvider to generate special characters

Tags: c#, encryption

i am using following encryption method to encrypt a string

```
      private static byte[] mKey = { };
      private static byte[] mIV = { 89, 23, 13, 17, 69, 32, 02, 79 };           
      private static string mStringKey = "lkj@788*";
      private static string Encrypt(string pText)
            {
                try
                {
                    mKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mStringKey.Substring(0, 8));
                    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pText);
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                    des.CreateEncryptor(mKey, mIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    cryptoStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                   
                   return string.Empty;
                }
            }
```

I want to build a discount code for customers with this format "CustomerId-PurchasedItem-DiscountValue"  and encrypt these (CustomerId,PurchasedItem,DiscountValue) strings individually and combine encrypted values adding "-" char between them to build discount code .while decrypting above encoded string ,i will split it with "-" char,and decode individually ,but i am afraid that while encrypting if it get "-" char then my logic will fail..is this method is safe or can any one suggest me another trick?or is there any trick that encryption of a string result to fixed length?

Comment: Would replacing a `-` with a different character (`$` for example) still cause issues? Otherwise you could maybe go with hex instead of base64?

Comment: @ic how can i be sure that this encryption will not produce ($) charachters?and if i make discount code with $ character discount code doesn't look nice isn't it??so i want to use - characters as much as possible :)

Comment: In fact wait a minute. You're using base64...there is no `-`.

Comment: Note that this sort of system is vulnerable to trivial replay attacks. What prevents a customer from combining parts of different codes to create their own code? Also note that DES is ridiculously weak. Anybody could brute force the key within days. (Except it's unnecessary now that your secret key is no longer secret.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that .NET's base64 encoding will never contain a '-' character, so you should be okay.